# Hibernate 5 .6.15 select count HQL query not working

Tags: java, hibernate

we are migrating from hibernate 3.1.3 to hibernate 5.6.15.Final  and using hibenate.cgf.xml and loading all hbm.xmls from cfg.xml . for count HQL  session.createQuery(select count(*) from Ticket ti ket).getUniqueResult  it returns 0 as count,but in DB table records are present. where Ticket is pojo class mapped in hbm.xml file.

trying to run query with session.createQuery and not returning expected result. its should return actual count of records . am not sure it has loaded all pojos classes.